# gobuffalo tx.Eager().Create causing error “could not set '%!s(int64=15)' to '<invalid reflect.Value>' ”

Tags: postgresql, go, buffalo

I'm trying to write data to PostgreSQL database with relationships using this code.

```
req := c.Request()

tx := c.Value("tx").(*pop.Connection)

user := &models.User{}

if req.FormValue("user_type") == "0" {
    salt, _ := strconv.Atoi(os.Getenv("SALT"))
    userType, _ := strconv.Atoi(req.FormValue("user_type"))
    user.UserType = int16(userType)
    user.Phone, _ = strconv.ParseInt(req.FormValue("phone"), 10, 64)
    hash, _ := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(req.FormValue("password")), salt)
    user.PassHash = string(hash)
    user.Balance = 0
    user.Validated = false
    user.Person = &models.Person{
        Name: req.FormValue("name"),
        City: req.FormValue("city"),
    }

} else {

}

err := tx.Eager().Create(user)

fmt.Println(errors.WithStack(err))

return c.Render(200, r.JSON(map[string]string{"message": "User successfully created"}))
```

User model:

```
type User struct {
ID        int64        `db:"id" rw:"w" form:"-"`
UserType  int16        `db:"user_type" form:"-"`
Phone     int64        `db:"phone"`
PassHash  string       `db:"pass_hash" form:"-"`
Balance   int64        `db:"balance" form:"-"`
Avatar    nulls.String `db:"avatar" form:"-"`
Validated bool         `db:"validated" form:"-"`
//Company   *Company     `has_one:"company" fk_id:"user_id"`
Person *Person `has_one:"person" fk_id:"user_id"`
}
```

Person model:

```
type Person struct {
ID     int64        `db:"id"`
Name   string       `db:"name"`
Email  nulls.String `db:"email"`
City   string       `db:"city"`
UserId int64        `db:"user_id"`
User   *User        `belongs_to:"user"`
}
```

`tx.Eager().Create` is only creating a row for User model. Row for Person model is not being created. When trying to print, the following error occurs without a stack trace.

> `could not set '%!s(int64=15)' to '<invalid reflect.Value>'`

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example to help us help you.

Comment: Try changing `UserId` to `UserID`.

Comment: @mkopriva 
Thank you very much. Changing UserId to UserID fixed the problem